# Show members of members group

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I want to show all members of the group in which the user is also member.
For this, I want to use the buddypress members loop:
http://codex.buddypress.org/developer/loops-reference/the-group-members-loop-bp_group_has_members/

As a permitted parameter, I try to get the group_id and start the members loop, but I always get the output "This group has no members.":

```
global $bp;
 $group = groups_get_group( array( ‘group_id’ => $group_id ) );

if ( bp_group_has_members( '$group' ) ) : ?>


<div id="member-count" class="pag-count">
    <?php bp_group_member_pagination_count() ?>
</div>

 <div id="member-pagination" class="pagination-links">
  <?php bp_group_member_pagination() ?>
 </div>

<ul id="member-list" class="item-list">
<?php while ( bp_group_members() ) : bp_group_the_member(); ?>

<li>
  <!-- Example template tags you can use -->
  <?php bp_group_member_avatar() ?>
  <?php bp_group_member_link() ?>
  <?php bp_group_member_joined_since() ?>
</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>

<?php else: ?>

<div id="message" class="info">
<p>This group has no members.</p>
</div>

<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at 
function bp_group_has_members
in
buddypress\bp-groups\bp-groups-template.php  ?

You can't pass a string '$group' to bp_group_has_members.

Try:

```
$this_id = bp_get_group_id();
echo "group id is: " . $this_id;  // make sure there is a value here. 
$has_members_str = "group_id=" . $this_id;
if ( bp_group_has_members( $has_members_str ) )
```

Comment: Hi shanebp, unfortunatly 'group id is:' is blank. I execute this code in new page and not in the loop. Is that a problem?

Comment: Yes, blank is a problem. If not on a group page, you need to specify the id. if ( bp_group_has_members( "group_id=10" ) )

Answer (score 0):

You can Show members of members group by using below code you just have to get id of group by using this method

> $group_id =  bp_get_group_id();

```
$group_id =  bp_get_group_id();
if ( bp_group_has_members( $group_id  ) ): ?>
<?php while ( bp_group_members() ) : bp_group_the_member(); ?>
<?php bp_group_member_name() ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<h2>You smell, you're not part of any groups.</h2>
<?php endif;
```